# What happened in Beirut?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare

Can someone explain to me what happened in Beirut? This is mentioned when Captain Price and Kamarov meet each other in *Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2019*.

Not to mention, in *Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare* on the second mission it is also mentioned.

So what is Beirut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't know.

This has never been explained in any official Call of Duty media.  It is implied that there was a mission in the past in Beirut (obviously) in which Price helped Kamarov out, thus the whole "You owe me" sort of deal.

Comment: oh~ So I guess. we still need to wait right? By the way, should I close this question? or just leave it?

Comment: @kit If this or another answer satisfies your question, you can mark it as accepted answer (the check item on the left). Otherwise, you could wait for an answer that does, or even answer it yourself, if you can.

Answer (score 3):

In 1983 the US marines barracks were attacked by a suicide bomb in Beirut killing more than 200 US marine.

You may read about what happened that day on Wikipedia.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1983_Beirut_barracks_bombings

Comment: Do you have any evidence of that bomb's connection to CoD MW? It would certainly fit into the timeline of the story, but something to back it up would be nice. Kamarov served under Price when he helped the SAS, so that would fit too. But neither are connected to Beirut in any way in the lore.

Comment: No I don't have any evidence that relates what happened in Beirut to the game, but throughout some search it seems that the barracks attack is the biggest event happened there, so if captain Price did mean a real historical event when he mentioned Beirut, I think that this event is what he meant.